# My knife tool is too "choppy"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

So I'm using the knife tool in AI CC to make some shading on an illustration I'm working on, but it gets too "choppy". I work with a mouse, so I just drag the cursor where I want to cut the shape. As I mentioned, the cut gets too choppy, it's not a smooth cut. Is there a setting so that Illustrator just smoothens the cut if my hand shakes a lot, like the brush settings? Or do you think it would be easier with a tablet, so I could just draw the cut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not that I'm aware of. If you dont like results you get out of knife use another tool instead.

For example you can use **line tool** ([image]) and **Object → Path → Divide Objects Below** combo. This is not too much work if you set a hotkey for divide objects below.

Other workflows are possible, such as a line and shape builder etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the knife tool is extra choppy when it has a smaller number of pixels to cut around. You could try scaling up your artwork temporarily for smoother cuts.

Answer (score 0):

The Knife Tool is a little crude, and has no smoothing controls.

Apart from joojaa's suggestion which will work, another alternative might be to draw a nice smooth line with the Pen Tool, and use the Shape Builder tool to cut up the image.

Example

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can make the resulting 'cut' from the knife tool smoother by simply creating the line more slowly. It seems to automatically smooth out the line as you go - the slower, the smoother.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!